# SQL-Could you help me writing a SQL query which remakes new table from existing table without duplicated ID?

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift

Could you help me write a SQL query which remakes a new table from existing table without duplicated ID?

I want to store most new data among all duplicated Id.

The table looks like this:

| Id | name | visited | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xd01s | sam | 23 | Null | string |
| sc01t | susan | 12 | string | string |
| t01sc | tom | 22 | Null | Null |
| xd01s | san | 12 | string | string |

My table (actually tables) is at Amazon Redshift DB. And while I'm storing my data there.

I found out same Id is getting duplicated regardless of primary key.

So I've decided to recreate the table without duplicated data (erasing seems costly).

From the example table, the new table I want would be like this.

| Id | name | visited | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sc01t | susan | 12 | string | string |
| t01sc | tom | 22 | Null | Null |
| xd01s | san | 12 | string | string |

Preserving latest data of 'xd01s' and getting rid of other old 'xd01s'.

Any of columns doesn't tell what is most recent one (there isn't time nor date..nor any incremented value).

I think the biggest rownumber from initial order is only way to notice most recent one. But my SQL query I've tried keeps failing (lack of experience..).

So far I've used this query with psycopg2 python package.

```
alter table my_table rename to my_table_old

create table my_table 
as 
    select distinct * 
    from my_table_old

drop table if exists my_table_old cascade
```

but this only gets rid of data which has all column values are same.

Great thanks for reading my question and answering it ^^.

Comment: Thank you, marc_s for editting my questions more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will do:

```
SELECT
    Id
    ,name
    ,visited
    ,column1
    ,column2
FROM    (
        SELECT
            Id
            ,name
            ,visited
            ,column1
            ,column2
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id)    AS rn
        FROM
            my_table_old
        )   AS my_table_aux
WHERE
    rn = 1
;
```

With the subquery we are creating a new column that assigns a sequential integer to each repetition of the same value within the field `Id`.

| Id | name | visited | column1 | column2 | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xd01s | sam | 23 | Null | string | 1 |
| sc01t | susan | 12 | string | string | 1 |
| t01sc | tom | 22 | Null | Null | 1 |
| xd01s | san | 12 | string | string | 2 |

The outer query filters the inner result to keep just the *first* of the rows within a group rows with the same *Id* (as we are sure that there will be at least one record for each `Id` with a `rn` value of 1).

| Id | name | visited | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xd01s | sam | 23 | Null | string |
| sc01t | susan | 12 | string | string |
| t01sc | tom | 22 | Null | Null |

Note that nothing guaranties that the result will keep the original order of the records. We would need a field to provide an `ORDER BY` clause for the `OVER` clause.

Let's suppose you have a datetime field named `updated_on` that can be used to sort the records from newest to oldest. In that case, the query should be as follows:

```
SELECT
    Id
    ,name
    ,visited
    ,column1
    ,column2
    ,updated_on
FROM    (
        SELECT
            Id
            ,name
            ,visited
            ,column1
            ,column2
            ,updated_on
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY updated_on DESC)   AS rn
        FROM
            my_table_old
        )   AS my_table_aux
WHERE
    rn = 1
;
```

Here you can read the details of [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_ROW_NUMBER.html) window function.

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful answer @Ricardo. 
though, I'm wondering about conditional sentence rn=1.

isn't it just getting first row?
wouldn't there be any way to keep most new data among 
same IDs?

Comment: I've edited the answer to follow up with your example. As for keeping the newest data, we need a column either on the table itself or in another table that we can cross with this one. Without a field that tell us how to sort data, I see no way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you, very much for your answer. 
I've checked it working.

though, I am not at position of what column to be at table, could you also give me query in case table have field that can tell orders(such as updated time)? 

if I'm lucky, my supervisor can take suggestion.

Comment: I've updated the answer to add an example with ORDER BY. Hope it helps.

Comment: It is more than helpful. thank you very much
though, my supervisor was bit disappointed at my approach. and asked me to fix query refer to this article.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-upsert.html